# Use google maps computeDistanceBetween to get the closest location returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Ok so I have set up a map and an autocomplete field on a testing site.

My goal is to get the user to input his/her address into the field and then when he/she clicks confirm work out the closest store to them based on the information provided.

I have the lat/long for each store and with the help of autocomplete I now have the lat/long of the users address but when I use the computeDistanceBetween method provided in the documentation I get NaN instead of a desired result.

Here is a link to the test site to get an idea - http://dev.touch-akl.com/map/

And Below is what I have tried so far

```
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    //--- Search Box -------------------------------------------------

    var input = document.getElementById('address');
    var $confirm = $('#confirm');

    var options = {
       types: ['geocode'],
       componentRestrictions: {country: 'nz'}//Turkey only
    };        

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    $confirm.click(function(){

        var _street = $('#address').val();
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        var _coordinates = place.geometry.location.toString();
        var _delivery = _coordinates.substring(1, _coordinates.length - 1);
        var _kCord = '-36.874694,174.735292';
        var _pCord = '-36.858317,174.782284'

        console.log(_coordinates);
        console.log(_delivery);

        console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(_pCord, _delivery));
        console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(_kCord, _delivery));


    });
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween requires that you feed it two google.maps.LatLng objects whereas you are using strings, and that won't work. The following should...

```
$confirm.click(function(){
    var _street = $('#address').val();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var _coordinates = place.geometry.location; //a google.maps.LatLng object
    var _kCord = new google.maps.LatLng(-36.874694, 174.735292);
    var _pCord = new google.maps.LatLng(-36.858317, 174.782284);

    console.log(_coordinates);

    console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(_pCord, _coordinates));
    console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(_kCord, _coordinates));
});
```