# Google Maps API (3) computeDistanceBetween returns NaN

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We're using Google Maps API to show a list of all our clinics on our website and I'm in the process of writing a 'Show all clinics near me' feature.  Everything is working fine and I have a circle being drawn on the map using the Google Maps Circle call from the geometry library.

We want to return a list of all clinics that fall within that circle.  Our clinics are loaded via a `$.get();` call from a separate .js file.  I've been messing with the `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pointA, pointB);` function to test if each clinic falls within the circle, where `pointB` is the center of the circle and `pointA` is the position of the clinic- both of which are being defined via `new google.maps.LatLng(clinic.lat, clinic.long));`.

`ComputeDistanceBetween` keeps returning `NaN` for every clinic.  Due to some sensitivity issues I cannot share the exact code I'm working with but I [modified a Google Maps API fiddle for marker clustering HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/dkaufmanjs/8p8mktcf/) because we're also using marker clustering and the lat/longs load similarly to ours.

I already checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822948/use-google-maps-computedistancebetween-to-get-the-closest-location-returns-nan) and it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. `locations[x].long` doesn't exist, that should be be `locations[x].lng`

so your function should be:

```
  var mylocation = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0].lat, locations[0].lng);
  console.log(mylocation);
  var marker_lat_lng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[2].lat, locations[2].lng);
  console.log(marker_lat_lng);
  var distance_from_location =  google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(mylocation, marker_lat_lng);
  document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = distance_from_location;
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8p8mktcf/3/)

Comment: Oh G-d D--- it!  Always something simple.  I've gone over this 100 times now and I apparently missed that everytime.  Let me try it out in my dev code and see how it shakes out.

Comment: That was it but in the case of dev code I had `long` instead of `lng`.  Oy.  Thanks!