# Custom place in Google place api android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am working on google maps api. I have added Markers in the map.I wanted to get my markers in the nearby places section.Is there any way to implement this? A help would be appreciated.

Comment: can we see your approach or code you used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get places near by your location, then check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search). A Nearby Search lets you search for places within a specified area. You can refine your search request by supplying keywords or specifying the type of place you are searching for.

> A Nearby Search request is an HTTP URL of the following form:
>
> `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters`
>   where output may be either of the following values:
>
> - json (recommended) indicates output in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
> - xml indicates output as XML

The following example is a search request for places of type 'restaurant' within a 500m radius of a point in Sydney, Australia, containing the word 'cruise' in their name:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Example from [GitHub](https://github.com/leemdoyun/android-education-project/blob/5530e15e64e1f19774bbaefe7ec17192dd9d9896/GoogleMapTest/src/com/example/googlemaptest/GooglePlaceConstant.java):

Check these related links:

- [Finding nearest locations using Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561296/finding-nearest-locations-using-google-map-api)
- [Show Current Location and Nearby Places and Route between two places using Google Maps API in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428209/show-current-location-and-nearby-places-and-route-between-two-places-using-googl)

Hope this helps!