# Get all coordinates inside an area

Tags: javascript, google-maps, data-structures, coordinates, closest

I'm working with google maps API and have a few coordinates (markers) around the world. How is the best way to get a marker list of the points inside a mile with an 'A' marker on center ?

The first way I think is calculate the distance between the point A and all others points and sort the array. It works, but takes **n** interactions.

The second way would store the coordinates and a 'chunk' (city, state, country), and repeat the previous method, searching only inside this "chunk". It's still **n**, but now the 'n' is smaller.

What is the best way to store the data and work on it ?

Comment: Your question is **too broad** and it's unclear. How are you storing the coordinates? What have you tried so far? Did you make any research before asking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561296/finding-nearest-locations-using-google-maps-api/16563642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store several ordered index- and coordinate-lists, each based on either x, y, or z, or longtitude or latitude information.

For example:

```
Points = {(2,3), (6,4), (7,1), (1, 9)};

xList = {1, 2, 6, 7};
xIndexList = {3, 0, 1, 2};

yList = {1, 3, 4, 9};
yIndexList = {2, 0, 1, 3};
```

Then you can filter the x-values within 1 mile from the x-coordinate of A and the same for the y-values and consider only the overlap of these indices. (You should still do a distance check for these points afterwards.)

It is a bit cumbersome though, and one should be careful around the poles and date-lines if using spherical coordinates, but it is at least fast.